# Azure Policy Deploying using Powershell

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template, azure-policy

I'm deploying a deny policy through powershell and get the following error

`New-AzPolicyDefinition : InvalidPolicyRule : Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'properties' on object of type 
'PolicyRuleDefinition'. Path 'properties'.'.`

The code I'm using is: 
1`New-AzPolicyDefinition`
    -name 'externalDeny’ 
    `-Policy 'C:\tmp\denyoms-temp.json'`
    -Parameter 'C:\tmp\denyoms-param.json' `

The policy templates are below.

Template File - https://pastebin.com/embed_js/HrjUWrvf
Parameter - https://pastebin.com/embed_js/QxEX92jf

I think it could be the tags, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the template. According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicydefinition?view=azps-3.7.0#description), the template should be in this format (template.json):

```
{
        "if": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "tags",
                    "Equals": "ExternalVM"
                },
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Compute"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
                    "in": "[parameters(\'notAllowedExtensions\')]"
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
        }
}
```

Also, a minor change in your parameters file, template expects a "Array" type as per the condition you have applied:

```
{
    "notAllowedExtensions": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The list of extensions that will be denied. Example: BGInfo, CustomScriptExtension, JsonAADDomainExtension, VMAccessAgent.",
            "displayName": "OmsAgentForLinux"
        }
    }
}
```

Use this command to execute:

```
New-AzPolicyDefinition -Name 'Not allowed VM Extensions' -Description 'This policy governs which VM extensions that are explicitly denied.' -Policy 'template.json'  -Parameter 'parameters.json'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but I'm still getting this error `InvalidPolicyRule : Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'properties' on object of type 
'PolicyRuleDefinition'. Path 'properties'.'.`

Comment: Did you updated the template file? Are you using the template, I added in the answer?

Comment: Hi, Yes sorry my fault, the command should have been `    New-AzPolicyDefinition -Name 'Not allowed VM Extensions' -Description 'This policy governs which VM extensions that are explicitly denied.' 
     -Policy 'C:\tmp\tempate.json' 
     -Parameter '{ "notAllowedExtensions": { "type": "array" } }'`` thanks again :)